# Toggle more than two div's in show/hide fashion

Tags: javascript

I have 10 different divs and 10 buttons.I can easily toggle(hidden/visible) them :

```
 <script>
    function fun(x)
    {        
    document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = 
    (document.getElementById(x).style.visibility != "visible") ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }
    </script>
    <div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden">div1</div><input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun('div1')">
    <div id="div2" style="visibility:hidden">div2</div><input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun('div2')">
```

Now what I want to do is: say,div1 is already visible,click button2,div2 gets visible along with all other divs(div1,div3,...div10) gets hidden if one of them are already visible in the click of button2 and so on. what should I do?

Comment: I think you want an accordion. Look at [this link](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). It uses jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJ6bW/2/

Add a reset function before running fun()

```
function reset(x) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div')).forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.id == x) {
            return false;
        }
        element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
}

function fun(x) {
    reset(x);
    document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = (document.getElementById(x).style.visibility != "visible") ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
```

Comment: awesome! couldn't get Array.prototype.slice.call().. @tom chung

Comment: Array.prototype.slice.call() is converting the NodeList object returned by document.querySelectorAll('div') into a array object.

Comment: You can use for(var i = 0;i<=document.querySelectorAll('div').length;i++){} if you like.